# How to search in a Collection with unknown structure?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I spent several hours reading through docs and forums, trying to find a solution for the following problem:

In A Mongo database, I have a collection with some unstructured data:

> {"data" : "some data" , "_id" : "497ce96f395f2f052a494fd4"}
>
> {"more_data" : "more data here" ,"recursive_data": {"some_data": "even more data here", "_id" : "497ce96f395f2f052a4323"}
>
> {"more_unknown_data" : "string or even dictionaries" , "_id" : "497ce96f395f2f052a494fsd2"}
>
> ...

The catch is that the elements in this collections don't have a predefined structure and they can be unlimited levels.

My goal is to create a query, that  searches through the collection and finds all the elements that match a regular expression( in both the keys and the values ).

For example, if I have a regex: '^even more' - It should return all the elements that have the string "even more" somewhere in the structure. In this case - that will be the second one.

Comment: If your use case is "during manual intervention, quickly locate a deeply nested object that is causing the issue" rather than "offer search feature in the application", then you should probably indicate this in the question, if only to prevent answers to the effect of "don't do it, it will be slow".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add an array to each object and populate it with the strings you want to be able to search on.  Typically I'd lowercase those values to make case-insensitive search easy.

e.g. Tags : ["copy of string 1", "copy of string 2", ...]

You can extend this technique to index every word of every element.  Sometimes I also add the field with an identifier in front of it, e.g. "genre:rock" which allows searches for values in specific fields (choose the ':' character carefully).

Add an index on this array and now you have the ability to search for any word or phrase in any document in the collection and you can search for "genre:rock" to search for that value in a specific field.

Comment: You should be aware of this method, since maximum indexed value is 800 bytes. I can't say exactly if it does not counts, when it separated on array elements. So it best to check this issue before you run in production. If you eventualy will make such check, please comment out...

Comment: Version 2 increased index key size to 1024.  Each array element is indexed.  The documentation does however warn *"The database creates an index entry for each item in the array. Note an array with many elements (hundreds or thousands) can make inserts very expensive."*

Comment: How I can write a repository method for the Spring Data Mongo ?

Comment: I.e. "don't solve your original problem, solve an easier problem instead".

Answer (score 0):

Ever if you will find a way to do this you will still face problem of slow searches, becouse there are no indexes

I had similar problem and solution was to create additional database(on same engine or any other more suitable for search) and to fill it with mongo keys and combined to one text field data. And to update it whenever mongodb data updates.

If it suitable you can also try to go this way...At least search works very fast. (I used postgresql as search backend)

Comment: These concerns are irrelevant if the use case is manual intervention |(i.e. quickly locate the one deeply nested object that is causing issues) rather than implementing a search feature in the application.