# Find documents where any field matches a search string

Tags: mongodb

I'm asking this question after studying MongoDB text search and keyword indexes. I also found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238181/mongodb-how-to-find-string-in-multiple-fields), but adding an array to each document containing all the field values seems like a kludgy solution. Thus this question.

We need to write a query that will return documents where any field matches a search string.

Our first thought was to write a query along these lines:

```js
db.collection.find( { field_one: /search string/i, 
                      field_two: /search string/i,
                      field_three: /search string/i } );
```

Our challenge is that the fields will vary between documents, so we can't hard-code the field names in the query.

Is something like the following pseudocode possible with MongoDB?

```js
db.collection.find( { [any field]: /search string/i } );
```

Comment: no, it's not possible to search for fields without knowing their name. this is typical of a database - it looks like you need a search engine rather than a database.

Comment: Hi Jedidiah - Did you find the solution? I also got the same requirement where I want to search string in whole documents of collection but where I am not aware field name (may always change) going to be.. Please help... Thanks, Deepali

Comment: @user4567570 it was so long ago now, I can't remember the exact details. But I'm pretty sure we went with `.find({ $where: function () {...} })` as the collections we were querying were not very large. See here for further explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19802670/825421

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it's not exactly what you are looking for, but if you are considering a schema restructure that allows such a query, this post appears to be interesting:

[MongoDB Query Help - query on values of any key in a sub-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802502/mongodb-query-help-query-on-values-of-any-key-in-a-sub-object)

Comment: Either one of the answers on that question should be a possible solution for us. Thanks!