# search for part of a string in the mongodb documents

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection  with the  following documents

```
1.question:"Best OS?"
2.question:"Best Mobile?"
3.question:"Worst OS?"
```

If i search for a string "Best" then it results then it must return 1 and 2 documents.
How to achieve this in mongo

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if a field contains a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610131/checking-if-a-field-contains-a-string)

Comment: what if i want to search all fields in a document???

Comment: You're changing the question now. That too has been covered dozens of times already. You'd need to use the beta text search feature of MongoDb or change the structure to put all values and keys in a new structure. Honestly, I'd suggest using a full text search engine. It's more more suited to this task than MongoDb.

Comment: Duplicate example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238181/mongodb-how-to-find-string-in-multiple-fields

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`$regex`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator:

```
db.collection.find( { question: /Best*/ } );
```

Comment: Might help to add that searching **anywhere** in the string is going to be bad for performance. And perhaps suggest some alternatives.