# mongo db indexing dropping and reindexing

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have multiple collections in my mongo db and have done indexing in few collections. Does these indexing effect my query on any collections whether it is indexed or not ? Should I drop all the indexing before doing query to make it fast and then at the end, reindex all those ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing affects the speed of only the collection you indexed (most of the time it affects it positively). So if you indexed collectionA and do something with collectionB, the time is irrelevant of A.

It is really hard to tell what do you mean in the second question. I suggest you to read more about [indexing in mongodb](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/), than may be read my another answer about indexes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19972011/1090562), than edit your question to make it more understandable.

Comment: does indexing twice on the same field effects ? I my javascript file, before doing query, I am doing indexing. So everytime I the .js file, the indexing is done on the same collection and same filed. Does this have any impact on performance ?

Comment: First of all you should not do indexing more than once. One time you created index on the field and this is it. All new elements in this collection will be indexed as well. Sure it has performance effect. And really bad effect.